# stuck at starting intent main activity react native app

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

Trying to run the react native app on mobile device connected using `react-native run-android`. The app build was successful but the app crash on opening and on the command prompt it stucks on `Starting: Intent { cpm=com.project.projectname/.MainActivity }`

The App installed on the mobile device but always keep stopping. Can someone help me how to debug this and i cant see where the error messages at.

this the whole command prompt output

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1109 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'C:\Users\user' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
        activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.DynamicLink$Builder

> Task :app:installDebug
09:26:46 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
09:26:46 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'R58M55ASZDM' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:26:46 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-A105G - 9' for app:debug
09:26:46 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'R58M55ASZDM'
09:26:46 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'R58M55ASZDM'
09:26:47 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
09:26:47 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
09:27:16 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'R58M55ASZDM' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:27:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
09:27:16 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
09:27:16 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'R58M55ASZDM' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:27:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20m 38s
62 actionable tasks: 59 executed, 3 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.project.projectname/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please run `adb logcat`, capture and share the logs when you start the app, only then we can find your true issues.

Comment: This thread is crazy disappointing, and should probably be taken down.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue start when I uninstalled the app from the current user but not all users. After uninstalling the app for all users it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

First of all run this command from terminal 
1. npm install
Please restart your whole project with editor and then run following commands
Before this two commands please check your local properties for Android SDK...
1. npm start
2. npm run android

Comment: npm start return this 
`warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...`

Note: Device already connected but nothing happens
and should i run the `npm run android` on separate terminal?

Comment: please kill all terminal and try again

Comment: now it returns `To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"` and the big logo of react native

Comment: is it run successfully on device or not?

Comment: nothing happens after i run `npm start` and `npm run android` still not done executing the command and it takes 20 or 30mins

Comment: still the same the app still crash when opening

Comment: Please send  screenshot of device screen

Comment: when app is crashing please check logcat of Android Studio it shows some error

Comment: where can i find the logcat sir?

Comment: at the bottom of Android Studio

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue, I just solved it using `sudo npm run android` command.

Output of `npm run andoird` without using `sudo`:

```
hesam@hesam:~/react-native/MyReactNative$ npm start android

> @ start /home/hesam/react-native/MyReactNative
> react-native start "android"

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /home/hesam/react-native/MyReactNative 

Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

info Opening developer menu...
```

Output of `npm run andoird` after using `sudo`:

```
hesam@hesam:~/react-native/MyReactNative$ sudo npm start android    
> @ start /home/hesam/react-native/MyReactNative

> react-native start "android"

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /home/hesam/react-native/MyReactNative 

Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

info Opening developer menu...
 BUNDLE  [android, prod] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (604/604), done.
```